# Writting on a file

Tags: c, linux, file

im working on a project for college and I have a problem. I have to manage a theatre room. Everything is fine about it, but now I have to copy the state of the room to a file.  When I call the function `guarda_estado_sala()`, which should print the ids of the clients in the file (stored at the variable `sala` which is a pointer), it doesn't do anything at all.  I even added a `printf` inside the function, but it doesn't work, any clues on why?

Here is the code (the function I need to change is marked with a comment):

```
//Cuerpo biblioteca
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <stdio.h>
//cabeceras archivos
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> //para close

int* sala;
int aforo;

void crea_sala(int capacidad){
    sala = (int*) malloc(capacidad* sizeof(int));
    aforo = capacidad;
    
    for(int i = 0; i<capacidad; i++){
        *(sala+i) = -1;
    }
    
}


int reserva_asiento(int id){
    for(int i = 1; i <= aforo; i++){
        if(*(sala+i-1) ==id){
            return -2;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 1; i <= aforo; i++){
        if(*(sala+i-1) ==-1){
            *(sala+i-1) = id;
            return i;
        }
    }
    
    return -1;
}


int libera_asiento(int asiento){
    int devuelve = *(sala+asiento-1);
    *(sala+asiento-1) = -1;
    return devuelve;
}


int estado_asiento(int asiento){
    if(*(sala+asiento-1) == -1){
        return 0;
    }else if(*(sala+asiento-1) > 0){
        return *(sala+asiento-1);
    }else{
        return -1;
    }
}


int asientos_libres(){
    int contador = 0;
    for(int i = 1; i<=aforo; i++){
        if(estado_asiento(i) == 0){
            contador++;
        }
    }
    return contador;
}


int asientos_ocupados(){
    return aforo-asientos_libres();
}


int capacidad(){
    return aforo;
}


void elimina_sala(){
    free(sala);
}


int encuentra_asiento(int id){
    for(int i = 0; i<aforo; i++){
        if(estado_asiento(i) == id){
            return i+1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}


// THIS IS THE FUNCTION:
int guarda_estado_sala(const char* ruta_fichero){
    int fd = creat(ruta_fichero, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH);
    for(int i=0; i<aforo; i++){
        write(fd, (char) *(sala+i), sizeof(char)); 
    }
    close(fd);
    return 0;
}

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "../cabeceras/sala.h"

void main(){
    crea_sala(10);
    reserva_asiento(10);
    guarda_estado_sala("saladeprueba.txt");
    elimina_sala();
}
```

Comment: many questions. where is "../cabeceras/sala.h", can we see it please. Why use such low level IO (creat, write)? What goes wrong? There is no output operation here, so nothing should get printed

Comment: The code is not doing any error checking, for example whether the file creation worked.

Comment: `guarda_estado_sala()` does not check whether its `creat()` call succeeds.  If it does not, then the `write()` and `close()` calls in that function will fail, too.  If `creat()` fails then it will tell you by returning `-1`.

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using standard `FILE` streams?

Comment: the tree of files goes like this sorry: practicas/lib/sala for the library of the theatre. practicas/fuentes for the test file and practicas/cabeceras for the headers.
about the operations, Im supposed to use the included libraries, with open/creat, write, read...

Comment: for all the comments got to say the file is being propertly created, I've checked it and the problem comes with the prints, dont really know why but the printing is not working in any of the functions called from the test.

Comment: you say nothing gets printed. There is nothing in this program that prints anything. Why do you expect it to print

Comment: Why call `write()` in a loop? Just do `write(fd, sala, aforo)` to write the whole thing all at once.

Comment: I added prints now to check the cause, and nothing gets printed

Comment: If this may be helpful, here is the compiling line for the library:
ar -crs libsala.a sala/sala.o
and for the test: 
gcc pruebas_sala2.c -o pt2 -lsala -L../lib
(LINUX)

Comment: I have the suspicion that the stout is being occupied by anything else but I dont really know by what.

Comment: _"the stout is being occupied"_ - Now I got thirsty ... From what line of code are you expecting something to be printed on the console?

Comment: "stout is being occupied by anything else" other than the stout Ted is now drinking, that's not a thing.  stdout is not *occupied* it is *written to* and simultaneous writes won't block each other (though their content will be interpolated together)

Comment: In the example there is no other prints, but I tried adding a random print (```printf("working")```) on the function "guarda_estado_sala" and nothing happened when called, even thought the function is returning values and  in the main function I can print the returned value

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong in multiple ways:

```c
write(fd, (char) *(sala+i), sizeof(char));
```

- `(char) *(sala+i)` This dereferences `sala[i]` and cast it to a `char`. You should supply a `void*`.
- `sizeof(char)` is not the correct size since you are writing `int`s. Corrected, it'd look like this:

```c
for(int i = 0; i < aforo; i++) {
    write(fd, sala + i, sizeof *sala);
}
```

but, there's no reason to do it in a loop. Just write it all at once:

```c
write(fd, sala, aforo * sizeof *sala);
```

Comment: im writting it on a loop because the intention is to add a separator later so I would set ```write(fd, ";", sizeof(char));

Comment: @NicolásMarcelo I see. Ok, then keep the loop, but use one that works, like the one I suggested above. Why add separators between `int`s in a binary file btw? Every `int` in the file will take up exactly `sizeof(int)` bytes so there's no need for separators.

Comment: the file must contain the id's of each client seated on the different seats, and later I will have another function which reads the state of each seat, so I need to separate the seats somehow Is there any better way to save them so can be ridden?

Comment: Keep in mind @NicolásMarcelo, that you are writing the *binary* representation of `int`s into a file, they won't be written in decimal notation, they'll be in binary and they can have all sorts of values, including the equivalent of `;`.  So the separator isn't just unnecessary, it is pointless because it's indistinguishable from valid value 59.  The file can be an exact map of the contents of the array byte for byte - you don't need a separator in the array, and you also don't need one in the file.

Comment: @NicolásMarcelo If the number of IDs and seats isn't fixed, a common way to deal with it is to start by writing to file how many ID's there are and then just write them out all at once. Do the same for the seats.  No separators needed.

Comment: Hi again Ted, I tried your way to print the file, and in a room with all seats non occupied (which is value 0 like is not occupied by any client ID) it just prints ÿ, I guess it is something related to the codification but I cant get to know what. I tried printing as ints, as chars...

Comment: @NicolásMarcelo The file you've created is in binary format. You need to read the binary data back into a variable of the same type you used to `write` to the file and then print the value.